# Create non-memoized selector on ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

Is it possible to create a non-memoized selector on ngrx?

I have a very small selector to check whether a value in the store is greater than Date.now().

```
export const selectAuthState = createFeatureSelector<AuthState>('auth');
export const hasTimeout = createSelector(
  selectAuthState,
  state => state.timeout < Date.now()
);
```

As expected, this selector is not useful since it won't be recalculated unless I change the value of `timeout`. Is there any way to make the selector non-memoized, so that it is recalculated every single time its value is accessed?

My current solution is creating a selector factory and using it every time, but I don't think it is the best solution:

```
export const hasTimeoutFactory = () => createSelector(
  selectAuthStatusState,
  state => state.timeout < Date.now()
);
```

Another solution would be doing something like

```
export const didTimeout = pipe(
  select(getTimeout), // using memoized value
  map(val => val < Date.now())
);
```

And then importing this pipe.

Answer (score 2):

A selector has a `release` method to reset the memoization, I think this is what you'd want to use.

This translates in the following code:

```
this.timeout = this.store.pipe(select(hasTimeout));
hasTimeout.release();
```

[Docs](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/selectors.md#reset-memoized-selector)

Comment: This probably won't work unless I release hasTimeout every time I use it, right? Also, is that better than the *pipe* solution?

Comment: yep, you'll need to release it every time. Another solution would be to keep the date in your store. Inside an effect you can dispatch an action to increment the date with 1 second for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So there is no way to create a non-memoized selector on ngrx?

Comment: I don't know but .release() doesn't work for me at all. The value is still memoized. :/

Comment: You can pass a custom memoizer to a selector that does not memoize https://github.com/ngrx/platform/pull/734/files

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and did the following - I'm fairly sure it is wrong in terms of NgRx architecture but it does what I want it to do.

```
export const selectAuthorizationDetails = createSelector(selectAuthorizationState, 
    (state: AuthorizationState, store: Store<AuthorizationState>) => store,
    (state: AuthorizationState) => new Date(),     // Force the selector memoization to fail which is probably the wrong thing to do
      (state, store, timeNow) => {
        if (state.lastUpdated != null) {
            let diffMs = timeNow.getTime() - state.lastUpdated.getTime()
            if (diffMs > 300000) {
                store.dispatch(refreshAuthorization());
                return null;
            }
            return state.authorizationDetails;
        }
        return null;
      }
  );
```

In the store my authorization details store the last updated time and so on each invocation, it tests whether they've expired or not. If I use memoization then it won't work and releasing the selector then has to be done on each call meaning I'd probably need to hide the selector behind a facade.

When using the selector in an AuthGuard, I simply filter on null so that I can always get the most up to date version but can cache the results for a pre-determined time (5 mins in this example)