# Unable to release memoization on ngrx selector

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

I am using NGRX in an angular app and using a selector to get the current job key as follows. Using this key, an image is taken from the document store.

I was looking at some links and it is advised that ngrx is a state store, not a document store. I found that using it as a doc store slows things down immensely.

https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage/issues/39

Anyway, the solution was to have a separate image store, and just handle the image key/identifier in ngrx state. Which works well.

```
this.store
    .pipe(select(getCurrentImage))
    .subscribe(async currentImageKey => {
        this.loadImage(currentImageKey);//Load and set the currentFile
    });
```

Later on in the app when the image is updated, but the image key/identified does not change, so i want to force an update by releasing the memoization from the selector. This should cause the image to be retrieved from the document store again.

This answer suggests releasing the memoization.

[Create non-memoized selector on ngrx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50920308/create-non-memoized-selector-on-ngrx)

So following that advice, have tried to release the selector before calling the image processing action.

```
async onAnalyseImage() {
    getCurrentImage.release();
    this.store.dispatch(
        ImageViewerActions.analyseImage({
            jobKey: this._currentFile.jobKey
        })
    );
}
```

Then once the action/effect are complete, i want to update the value of the current image with some changes however the key in the state has not changed. So i release the selector, which should set the memoization value to null.

```
on(ImageViewerActions.refreshImageCanvas, state => ({
    ...state,
    currentLoadedImage: state.currentLoadedImage,
})),
```

The "refresh" action is called and reducer tries to set the state value to the same value in the hope that the selector will be called again.

This does not happen and memoization persists. I can change to another image, and as expected, the selector is called and updates the image.

However, i cannot get a refresh on the same value key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The currentLoadedImage is a string.

The memoization does a string comparison and in Javascript a string is a string is a string.

So even though a new string object could be passed, it will still appear as the same object. a===b

Comment: I'd consider this a bug. After `release()` it shouldn't have a value to compare to.